# Odd sed behavior when replacing start of the line

Tags: bash, sed

I've run across a weird bit of behavior on BSD sed from Mac OS X.

```
sed -e '{s/^/   /;s/\(a*\)/\1b/;}'
```

So this basically just adds a few spaces to the start of the line, then replace any number of consecutive 'a' with the same thing followed by a b.

Expected:

```
|Input    |Output
|a        |   ab
|aa       |   aab
|aaa      |   aaab
```

Actual:

```
|Input    |Output
|a        |b   a
|aa       |b   aa
|aaa      |b   aaa
```

Reversing the order of these two commands results in the expected result. My understanding of the thing that is being done is a line is read into the pattern space, then all of the expressions are applied to it in order, then the next line is read into the pattern space and the process is repeated. There seems to be some

I have also tried

```
sed -e '{s/^/   /;s/\(a+\)/\1b/;}'
```

Which does nothing at all except add the spaces.

My question is, why is replacing the beginning of the line having this effect?

Comment: Your second regex always matches at the beginning of the string. The first substitution doesn't change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` means *zero or more*, not *one or more*. Since *zero or more `a`* can be anything, the `b` gets placed right at the start of the line - which is the earliest possible position.

The `+` is not understood by [posix regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html), which are used by `sed`.

---

You can use:

```
sed -e 's/^/   /;s/\(a\{1,\}\)/\1b/;'
```

`\{1,\}` means *one or more* and is general, meaning you can use it also for matching groups, like this:

```
\(foo\)\{1,\}
```

If you are looking for a single, repeated character you can just use:

```
aa*
```

(thanks [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332470/odd-sed-behavior-when-replacing-start-of-the-line/46332524#comment79625836_46332524) for reminding me on that)

Comment: In this case `aa*` would be simpler.

Comment: @melpomene That's true. I've added that.

Comment: Could you edit this to clearly show OP why your pattern works and his fails to do what he expects. It may be clear to you and me how your answer resolves his problem, but you haven't actually pointed out the problem.

Comment: I've added that.

Comment: Thank you, now I can in good conscience give you the +1 you deserve

Comment: I suppose I wasn't clear. The behavior totally changes if I swap the two. 

I.E.: 
        sed -e '{s/\(a*\)/\1b/;s/^/   /;}' 

Results in:

           ab
           aab

Comment: Yeah, sure. Read and understand the first paragraph

Comment: I see, yes. By doing the first expression first it matches the zero at the start. By doing it second it matches all the "a's" it can find. That makes sense.

Comment: Glad that you found it :)

Comment: I seem to recall it as greedy, but that doesn't extend to the entire string it seems.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: My fault here was I was thinking it would match the longest string in the line, not just the first longest string. So I was staring at it, I understood how it was matching the start of the line, but I kept looking at it as "One a is greater than zero, this should be replacing the longer match later in the line."